# How to increase my array size to get increased, each time there is an input from a user?

Tags: c#

I am writing data from user's input into a text file in c#, using array.

I have tried using array and ArrayList, yet it didn't work.

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("FirstName.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] thearray = new string[1];
    thearray[0] = str;
    w.WriteLine(thearray[0]);
    w.Flush();
    fs.Close();
```

It should insert the user's values to the array, and from the array to the text file.

Comment: Why are you adding the input string to array and just not writing it to the file directly with w.WriteLine(str)

Comment: Because of my teacher said we should use array to write to the file, so that it can be retrieved from the file as a row

Comment: Use a List<string> ? if needed, .ToArray() if you need an array later ?

Comment: Please help me mordify the code with your solution.

Comment: @SolomonAkinbiy. Then there is some problem with your logic. I do not see a loop to keep taking user input. Also use LeBigCat suggestions to use a list and convert it to array at the time of writing.

Comment: Use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1 go nuts.

Comment: Please help me mordify the code with your solution. Please

Comment: If you want to keep it an array and not use list, here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks, let me make a research on it.

Comment: Thanks i got it....

Comment: But how do I assign the users input to the array? I am using Array.

Comment: Why are you using an array if you need to resize it? Either append each line as they enter them or store the input in a `List<string>` (which is basically a resizable array) and then use `File.AppendAllLines(filePath, contentsList)`

Comment: how do I assign two textboxes to two text files through array

Answer (score 0):

The `List<string>` is more usable for this type problems. Because you don't need to specify the limit. To use arrays you must specify the member count, after that the computer will reserve memory places for your array. Increasing the capacity of array is kinda difficult. If you really have to use arrays you can follow the following solution.

Firstly, create an array with default length and create an integer that holds the last free index of your array.

```
string[] myArray = new string[5];
int freeID = 0;
```

And here the function that increases your array size.

```
public static void IncreaseMe(ref string[] oldArray)
{
   string[] newArray = new string[oldArray.Length * 2];
   for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.Length; i++)
   {
      newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
   }

   oldArray = newArray;
}
```

To increase array capacity, firstly you should create a new array with double times bigger than your array. You can specify it, for example +10 more size of old array. After that with a for loop you must carry your old array's elements to new array.

Usage:

```
int freeID = 0;
string[] myArray = new string[5];

for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    if(freeID >= myArray.Length)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("---Increasing Length of Array");
       IncreaseMe(ref myArray);
       Console.WriteLine("New Length = " + myArray.Length);
    }

     myArray[freeID] = i + ". Element";
     Console.WriteLine(myArray[freeID]);
     freeID++;
}
```

When you create an array, computer fills it the default value of your array's type. We need to know how many times we added element to our array. So the `freeID` will help us for that. When we add new element to array, we will check the is free id is equal or bigger than our array's length. If it is, before adding new element, increase the array size.

Comment: Microsoft has kindly been doing all of the work of your IncreaseMe method for a long time : [Array.Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-3.5)

Comment: Yes, but he mention it 'Because of my teacher said we should use array to write to the file'. It's probably a homework for beginners. So he just want to know how to code it.

Comment: how do I assign two textboxes to two text files through array

Comment: from the array to the textfiles